# port scanner not working in python

Tags: python, optparse

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import optparse
import socket
from socket import *
def connScan(tgtHost, tgtPort):
        try:
                connSkt = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
                connSkt.connect((tgtHost, tgtPort))
                connSkt.send('ViolentPython\r\n')
                results = connSkt.recv(100)
                print '[+]%d/tcp open'% tgtPort
                print '[+] ' + str(results)
                connSkt.close()
        except:
                print '[-]%d/tcp closed'% tgtPort
def portScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts):
        try:
                tgtIP = gethostbyname(tgtHost)
        except:
                print "[-] Cannot resolve '%s': Unknown host" %tgtHost
                return
        try:
                tgtName = gethostbyaddr(tgtIP)
                print '\n[+] Scan Results for: ' + tgtName[0]
        except:
                print '\n[+] Scan Results for: ' + tgtIP
        setdefaulttimeout(1)
        for tgtPort in tgtPorts:
                print 'Scanning port ' + tgtPort
                connScan(tgtHost, int(tgtPort))
def main():
        parser = optparse.OptionParser("usage%prog " +\ "-H <target host> -p <target port>")
        parser.add_option('-H', dest='tgtHost', type='string', \ help='specify target host')
        parser.add_option('-p', dest='tgtPort', type='string', \ help='specify target port[s] separated by comma')
        (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
        tgtHost = options.tgtHost
        tgtPorts = str(options.tgtPort).split(', ')
        if (tgtHost == None) | (tgtPorts[0] == None):
                print parser.usage
                print '[-] You must specify a target host and port[s].'
                exit(0)
        portScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts)
if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()

getting an error that :
 File "scanner.py", line 33
    parser = optparse.OptionParser("usage%prog " +\ "-H <target host> -p <target port>")
                                                                                       ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is interpreting the bare `\` character as 'I will continue on the next line', so the short version is to remove the \, making the line:

```
    parser = optparse.OptionParser("usage%prog " + "-H <target host> -p <target port>")
```

If you wanted to keep it, and to demonstrate how you use line continuation, you would press enter immediately after the `\`:

```
parser = optparse.OptionParser("usage%prog " +\
     "-H <target host> -p <target port>")
```

Note that there is nothing, not even a space, after the `\` in that last example.

If you're wanting nmap functionality rather than just doing this for the pleasure of learning, it's worth checking out the python-nmap module: http://xael.org/norman/python/python-nmap/

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scanner.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "scanner.py", line 45, in main
    portScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts)
  File "scanner.py", line 31, in portScan
    connScan(tgtHost, int(tgtPort))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '21,22,80'

Recent error I'm getting after compiling it,after giving the desired ip address and port numbers to be scanned.

Comment: What does the `print 'Scanning port ' + tgtPort` tell you?  It looks like '21,22,80' are not split by ', ' but rather by just ',', meaning your split(', ') in main() is not working.

Comment: Scanning port 21,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scanner.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "scanner.py", line 45, in main
    portScan(tgtHost, tgtPorts)
  File "scanner.py", line 31, in portScan
    connScan(tgtHost, int(tgtPort))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '21,'